# Use Token in RestTemplate

Tags: java, resttemplate

I want to use this RestTemplate code to make POST requests.

```
@Bean(name = "simpleRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate getRestClient() {

        RestTemplate restClient = new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
        restClient.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("username", "password"));
        HttpEntity<PaymentTransaction> request = new HttpEntity<>(new PaymentTransaction());
        ResponseEntity<PaymentTransaction> response = restClient.exchange("http://example.com", HttpMethod.POST,
                request, PaymentTransaction.class);
        PaymentTransaction foo = response.getBody();

        return restClient;
    }
```

How I can add Toke authentication into the HTTP link?

Probably the easiest way is to use `exchange("http://example.com" + "/" + token, HttpMethod.POST,`

Is there any better way?

Comment: OAuth token information? Because that would be in the headers. What your example looks like is you want to add a path segment to the request URI. Which are you looking for?

Comment: I want to add a path segment to the request URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @nickb commented, authentication is best done in HTTP headers.

If you really need to inject a token in the URL, you can implement a custom interceptor.

Pseudo code:

```java
final String tokenValue = "something";

restClient.getInterceptors().add(new ClientHttpRequestInterceptor() {

    @Override
    ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request,
                         byte[] body,
                         ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
                         throws java.io.IOException {

        URI modifiedUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(request.getURI())
        .query("token={tokenPlaceholder}")
        .buildAndExpand(tokenValue)
        .toUri();

        request.setURI(modifiedUri);
    }
});
```

There are many reasons for not doing that, for instance:

1. Systems that intercept and logs URL would log the token too, allowing 3rd parties to impersonate your users
2. You need to parse the token from the URL while dealing the rest of the query in the POST body request

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html

Answer (score 3):

Check out [`UriComponentsBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html):

```
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://example.com")
    .pathSegment(token)
    .build()
    .toUri();
```

Then you can use [`exchange()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-) that takes a `URI` as its first parameter.

```
restClient.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, PaymentTransaction.class);
```